# How to translate Python's BytesIO function to Node.js/TypeScript?

Tags: python, node.js, typescript, stream, buffer

I am currently in the process of merging my Python backend with a Svelte frontend using Svelte-Kit with the Node.js adapter. I have a media file as a Buffer and I am trying to figure out how to keep everything in-memory, similar to how I was able to do it in Python using BytesIO.

Here is the Python function I am trying to translate into TypeScript / Node.js:

```
def get_duration(input: BytesIO):
    command = "ffmpeg -i -".split(" ")
    output = subprocess.run(
        command,
        input=input.read(),
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    )
    duration = None
    lines = output.stderr.decode().split("\n")
    print(lines)
    for line in lines:
        if "Duration:" in line:
            match = re.search(r"Duration: (\d+):(\d+):(\d+.\d+)", line)
            if match:
                hours = int(match.group(1))
                minutes = int(match.group(2))
                seconds = float(match.group(3))
                duration = hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds
            break
    input.seek(0)
    print(duration)
    return duration
```

This function works fine in Python, but I am unsure how to translate this to Node.js while keeping everything in-memory. I need to pipe the bytes into stdin, and pipe the stdout and stderr to an in-memory object.

I suspect this might involve Node.js's "fs" library, but I am unsure whether to use streams or buffers.

Note: I am not using ffprobe for duration because it was constantly producing zeroes for duration (likely due to an error on my end).

I have tried using GPT-4, searching through Node.js documentation, and browsing StackOverflow for answers about piping to and from memory. However, I am not as familiar with Node.js as I am with Python, and Python's higher level abstraction for objects allowed me to avoid learning about streams, buffers, bytes, etc.

GPT-4 suggested that it was impossible to do what I did in the Python function using Node.js, but I find that hard to believe.

I have also looked into createWriteStream(), but the first parameter seems to require a FileLike object, and I don't think a Buffer fits that context.

Comment: `node` and `JavaScript` can work in different way and searching something similar to `BytesIO` can be useless. I expect It may use normall array to keep bytes in memory.

Comment: I dont really understand what exactly should the node.js script do, should it take the video content via stdin and print you only the duration of it? Do you intend to use the script via pipes like `cat video.mp4 | node magic.js` ? Anyways, you dont need the `fs` library. `fs` is meant to work with the filesystem. Instead you will need `child_process` standard library. It's pretty easy to use. I would provide you with more details, but clarification is needed.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out via Readable and Writables. I was having issues with the tests exiting early due to errors on the stdin. Turns out that was caused by Vitest running tests using multiple workers. I also switched back to FFProbe, which doesn't seem to be having the same issues it did with Python.

Here's what it looks like to return the duration of a video or audio file in seconds, while keeping everything in memory:

```
export async function getDuration(input: Buffer): Promise<number | undefined> {
    if (!Buffer.isBuffer(input)) {
        throw new Error('Input must be a buffer.')
    }

    if (input.length === 0) {
        throw new Error('Input must have a length.')
    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const output = spawn(
            'ffprobe',
            ['-i', '-', '-show_entries', 'format=duration', '-print_format', 'json'],
            {
                stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe']
            }
        )

        let jsonOutput = ''

        output.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
            jsonOutput += data
        })

        output.on('exit', (code, signal) => {
            console.log(`ffprobe exited with code ${code} and signal ${signal}`)
            if (code !== 0) {
                reject(new Error(`FFprobe exited with code ${code}`))
                return
            }

            try {
                const { format } = JSON.parse(jsonOutput)
                resolve(Number(format.duration))
            } catch (err) {
                reject(err)
            }
        })

        // Create a Readable stream from the input buffer
        const stream = new Readable()
        stream.push(input)
        stream.push(null) // indicates end-of-file

        // Pipe the stream to the stdin of the ffprobe process
        stream.pipe(output.stdin)

        // Handle EPIPE error
        output.stdin.on('error', (error) => {
            if (error.code !== 'EPIPE') {
                reject(error)
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Definitely more verbose than Python...

I imagine transcoding would be the same way, except having the output pipe to a Writable instead.